# Random TextNode appearing in Django authentication templates

Tags: django, textnode

I am using custom templates with django.contrib.auth.urls and I've noticed that in the top left corner I have plain text appearing that isn't part of my template e.g. "Password Reset" on the password reset page, "Password Change" on the change password page etc.

When I use my browser to inspect the element it simply appears as plain text in the page source. When I click the relevant line in the page source some properties appear in the side panel and it appears to be a "Text Node" with a value of the text that is shown in my template.

The text only shows on change password and reset password related pages (including reset done etc). It doesn't show on the login page or any other page in the app.

What is this and how do I get rid of it?

I have used django.contrib.auth.urls with custom templates before and have not come across this before.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show your template... If it extends some template that tries to display some sort of title show that part too.

Comment: Thank you - that was enough for me to go on. My page titles were populated with a tag called "title". Changing this to say "custom_title" fixed it. So appears to have been a clash over the use of "title".